# How can I fix "The creation of swap space in partition #6 of SCSI2 (0,0,0) (sda) failed" while installing Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, installation, dual-boot, partitioning, swap

**Edit: Updated my question with screenshots**

I have a 500 GB built-in hard disk.

I have 3 primary partition.

```
C: - 100GB - Primary Partition - Windows 7 installed
D: - 150GB - Primary Partition
E: - 100MB - Primary Partition - System Reserved For Windows
250GB - Unallocated Space
```

Please note, I already have a ubuntu installation in my windows 7(wubi)
Problem is I have ubuntu 13.04, but I need 12.04 LTS.

So I decided to install ubuntu 12.04 LTS in my `250GB Unallocated space`

I downloaded `ubuntu-12.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso` from official ubuntu site. I burned that in my 8GB transcend flash drive using ubuntu 13.04 built-in `start up disk creator`.

I booted my pendrive using boot manager.  I selected "install ubuntu", then selected "Something else" option.

I created a Logical partition with size 240GB (ext4 - path `/`). I also created another 10 GB Logical partition for Linux swap.

Everything's fine so far. However, I'm unable to proceed.

It says error something like `The creation of swap space in partition #6 of SCSI2 (0,0,0) (sda) failed`.

Can someone tell me what is wrong with my steps?

Thank you.

### Update:

I have added some screenshots to make my situation clear.

**1) Free space 247GB available**

[image]

**2) New logical partition with 237GB**

[image]

**3) After 237GB partition 10 GB Free space available**

[image]

**4) Create Linux swap with 10GB**

[image]

**5) Both partition look like this**

[image]

**6) When I click install button, I got this error**

[image]

**7) When I click ignore button, I got this error again**

[image]

**8) When I click "ok" button, I got redirected to this page**

[image]

**9) I restarted my PC, did the same steps again.. This is how it looks like now**

[image]

**10) When I click install, I got this error**

[image]

**11) So I edited my partition and selected "Mount point"**

[image]

**12) Now it looks like this**

[image]

**13) When I click install button, I got this error again.**

[image]

Is it really a bug with linux 12.04.3 or am I missing something?

Comment: Can you be more specific on how you made your partitioning? You can only have 4 primary partitions, so unless you created an extended partition and 2 logical partitions inside it that is normal.

Comment: @Salem I had unallocated free space when I install ubuntu. I created a new partition from there with the following option (Chose "Logical" instead of "Physical" - Size 240000 - Checked format option - Selected ext4 - Selected "/" from the dropdown for path )  As for swap I did the following (Chose "Logical" instead of "Physical" - Size 10000 - Selected "Linux swap")

Comment: @Salem Updated my question with screenshots.

Comment: You can choose Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7, it will not harm your system.

Comment: @Danatela Did you actually read my question?

Comment: Of course I did, but you did not explain why do you want to use manual partitioning. If you think it will install inside wubi installation, then you are wrong. It will use unallocated space.

Comment: @Danatela Like I stated in my question, I need ubuntu 12.04. I already have ubuntu 13.04 inside my windows 7. There is no easy downgrade option available in ubuntu. So I created a new 237GB partition to install ubuntu 12.04. To know more about the story please check screenshot 1 to 13

Comment: Just try to create swap before `/` partition.

Comment: @Danatela I have 6GB memory. So swap space is not really necessary. I even tried to install without swap partition. In such cases it throws error like `The creation of ext4 in partition #5 of SCSI2 (0,0,0) (sda) failed`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10441/discussion-between-danatela-and-giri)

Comment: Try this once.. Hope it works for you.. Boot from pre-installed Ubuntu 13.04. Using `gparted` on un-allocated space create an `Extended` partition. When a new `Extended` partition will be created then divide it by creating two `Logical` partitions one for `Ubuntu 12.04` installation and one for your `Swap`. So after creation of extended it would show `/dev/sda4 : Extended` under that `/dev/sda5` and `/dev/sda6`. Result may vary also but should be in same format. Just give it a try, I am much sure it will work for you.

Comment: @SauravKumar Please post that as an answer. Note that the "Format?" option should be unchecked during the installation, so that it will not try to recreate the partitions made by Gparted.

Comment: @ignis: Check my answer.. And edit if I missed something..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay! Don't make a Logical Partition. Why? It may install fine, but when you decide to upgrade to a later version of Ubuntu, it "may" (or may not) alter your partition table and you "may" (or may not) end up losing data. (I've experienced it.).

The solution? Use the entire free space for Ubuntu, and create a swapfile later. Check this for the process: [Use swapfile instead of partition and hibernate](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1042946)

Please create swap 1.5 times your RAM if <2 GB, 4GB if =3GB and 100-200MB more than RAM if >3GB. Don't "waste" 10GB HDD space.

P.S. Why is your /dev/sda1 'unknown'? If it's a Windows partition, it should've been of the 'type' `ntfs`. Boot into Windows or the Live DVD and see if the partition is usable. Delete it if not so.

Answer (score 3):

Try this once.. Hope it works for you..

- Boot from pre-installed Ubuntu 13.04.
- Using gparted on un-allocated space create an Extended partition.
- When a new `Extended` partition will be created then divide it by creating two `Logical` partitions one for Ubuntu 12.04 installation and one for your Swap.
- So after creation of extended it would show:

  - /dev/sda4 : Extended. under that

    - /dev/sda5 and
    - /dev/sda6.

  Result may vary also but should be in same format.

Just give it a try. Then try to install Ubuntu on pre-formatted partition.  Note that the `Format?`option should be unchecked during the installation, so that it will not try to recreate the partitions made by Gparted.

Yes Ubuntu will be upgraded to newer newer version. I installed Ubuntu 12.04.2 then upgraded to 12.04.3, I'd installed using this way.