# Install Ubuntu 15.04 alongside Windows 8.1 in UEFI mode

Tags: dual-boot, 15.04, uefi, windows-8

It seems like a repetitive question, but its is not. If it is, please guide me.

I have bought a new PC with following configuration

- Motherboard - Gigabyte (Socket 1150, Intel H81, GA-H81M-S1)
- Processor - Intel i5-4460 3.2GHz
- HDD (500GB) -

  - C: 100GB with windows 8.1 installed (NTFS)
  - D: 250GB empty (NTFS)
  - E: 125GB empty (NTFS)
- RAM - 8GB (Transcend)
- Graphics Card - Nvidia GT610 2GB

In my C: drive, i have windows 8.1 already and i am trying to install Ubuntu 15.04 alongside Windows 8.1.

I downloaded the iso for the same and burn it on DVD. And here are the steps i am following:

- Load it as a live OS DVD.
  [image]
- Live OS loaded.
  [image]
- Enabled the internet.
  [image]
- Started installing Ubuntu 15.04
  [image]
- Selecting options.
  [image]
- On clicking continue in previous step i got this message, i thought it might be a warning tried to skip this.
  [image]
- It is not able to detect any operating system, hence i selected the option "Something Else"
  [image]
- As you can see all my parititions.
  [image]
- I tried creating swap of 8GB, same as the RAM size in the drive representing E: drive for windows.
  [image]
- I got some warning for data back up which seems fine.
  [image]
- Then it flagged an error, swap cannot be created.
  [image]
- Then i created rest of the space of E: drive (in respect of windows) as ext4 partition for / (root)
- Then on clicking continue, i again got this error and i can't continue further, hence i have to forcefully shutdown.
  [image]

Some one told me to upgrade bios, i tried doing it but I did something horribly wrong, after that computer stopped working. Luckily I had taken the backup of current bios, hence able to revert back the previous state. If bios upgrade is required, please suggest which one? Else, what should I do to install Ubuntu 15.04?

**As per further suggestions, i tried further steps:**

I even tried disabling the UEFI mode from boot setup:
- Those are the two options i was able to find related to UEFI mode:
   [image]

[image]

- creating swap
  [image]
- creating ext4 partition
  [image]
- this is how the final structure.
  [image]
- clicking continue, got the same error as swap cannot be created.
  [image]

Please Help, i think this is not going to work out?

- **I tried with simple ext4 partition creation, not having swap. It failed at the end.**

[image]

Comment: See my answer to [this question.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/670914/uefi-problem-when-installing-ubuntu-15-04) Yours is a duplicate, but I can't flag it as such because the duplicate question is new enough that its answers have yet to be accepted or receive up-votes.

Comment: @RodSmith thanks for the comment, i tried same by changing options related to UEFI. Please find my updated question with screenshots. Please suggest, is there anything i am missing? It would be a great help.

Comment: I actually cant remove windows too and reinstall coz it came already installed and i dont have the DVD for reinstalling. So what do you suggest? Is there any else distro (Centos etc) i can try?

Comment: You must force Ubuntu to install in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode. You can *usually* do this by using the computer's built-in boot manager and launching the Ubuntu installation disk with the option that *lacks* the string "UEFI" in the description. Unfortunately, this detail varies from one computer to another, so I can't be more precise or even promise that it will work. If it doesn't work, you may need to delete the `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi` file from the boot medium to force a BIOS-mode boot. I wrote all of this in my answer to the linked-to question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu and all other GNU/linux doesn't work under NTFS.
Format one of your drives as ext4 in which you want to install Ubuntu.

For example you may click on /dev/sda6 and click "-" to delete ntfs partition.
Then you may click "+" and make that ext4 partition and then proceed.

Comment: I will try this. But same i did with making it as free volume too, coz i was thinking the same. Hence i am little doubtful about this solution. Is there any possibility related to bios? But still i will try once again and will get back to you.

Comment: I think installing ubuntu in legacy(not UEFI) with secure boot off will be good. I dont think there is anything wrong with BIOS.

Comment: Ok. then will start focussing on HD format type. Let me check and will get back to you.

Comment: Nope buddy, It didn't help. Please suggest anything else i might be missing?

Comment: Refer [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/339677/how-can-i-fix-the-creation-of-swap-space-in-partition-6-of-scsi2-0-0-0-sda)

Comment: thanks. I am able to see similar problem with others too. So as per the answer in the link, will that be ok if i dont create swap space.. I can create it later, right? And in one of his (person who asked the question) comments, he has posted that  "I have 6GB memory. So swap space is not really necessary. I even tried to install without swap partition. In such cases it throws error like The creation of ext4 in partition #5 of SCSI2 (0,0,0) (sda) failed" Any how i will try the same definitely by evening. If it works it would be a great help. Else i will ping u with more screenshots :)

Comment: I think i will go with ext4 with free space and lets see what happens.

Comment: Looks like a Good idea !

Comment: i tried the same way. Either i am doing something silly, else something major is going wrong? I am using Windows8.1 on C drive. Please let me know any else information i can attach. I am completely stuck here.

Comment: Case study to understand why it might be failing. Suppose that you have 50 bit of space(say from address 1 to address 50).You have NTFS between address 1-20. You have another NTFS between 26-45. So,you have 10 bits unallocated space which you can use. But the address of memory is not continuous(free memory is between address 21-25 and 46-50) . Now , you want to use remaining 10 bits as ext4 , but you are unable to do so because the address of that space is not continuous.

Comment: If this is true, you will succeed in creating smaller partitions. For example try creating only swap leaving all other space unallocated.

Comment: yes it make sense. But now i had tried everything. What you suggest? Can install whole windows 8.1 in legacy mode and then install ubuntu 15.04? This might be the solution?

Comment: yes, that might be a possible solution. Alternatively,  if you are able to make many smaller partitions then you can also install ubuntu in say ~20 gb and  use the remaining space for data storage(in many  small partitions).

Comment: Thanks all for your responses and patience. Last night i formatted everything and made single 500GB HD for ext4 partition using GParted. and was able to install ubuntu 15.04 completely with all possible options. Now, as my windows etc is gone, hence i can play or start over completely. So what you suggest will be easy, to start with windows and then ubuntu or vice versa? will 20GB is Ok for ubuntu for future perspective for installing more softwares. I am thinking of 100(C:) + 250 (D:) + 70 (E:) + 70 (F:).

Comment: C: drive will make for Windows,,, I will delete the partition of F: from windows, format as ext4 using GParted and will proceed with Ubuntu installation. This seems correct? This all will be done in Legacy mode.Or i can do both in UEFI mode? because, using GParted, i came to know that this whole issue was because of partition format only. Hence might be UEFI is good to go?

Comment: Install windows first. Let it delete your Ubuntu 15.04 (and all the disk). Create 100(C:) + 250 (D:) on windows and leave other space unallocated. Then while installing Ubuntu use that space as ext4 . Always allocate space for drives from the beginning(on both windows and ubuntu).Try to do everything in legacy. But some versions of windows might not work in legacy, then you may use UEFI. But for ubuntu use legacy with secure boot off.

Comment: But i think Windows 8.1 will only boot in UEFI. Is it true? Can i install Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu both in UEFI mode? Because i had installed ubuntu in UEFI mode only but with ext4 partition. I think both will work in UEFI mode. Let me try it today night.

Comment: Yes, windows 8.1 requires UEFI. But i  recommend you to install ubuntu in legacy with secure boot off. In UEFI , ubuntu might give you the error you were getting in the begining "This machines firmware has started in UEFI mode but it looks it might already have an os installed ~~ blah blah"

Comment: yes  same as screenshot above. But if i have the proper partition it might install.. Wait, let me try with all options tonight and i ll update. Lets see what happens.

Comment: Hi. Here is what i did.. I installed Windows 8.1 in C: drive, kept D: drive for storage and left E: drive unallocated. Then i had installed ubuntu 15.04 in E: drive, which happened correctly with no error. But when i am restarting, only ubuntu is booting up. I can see windows file too, using Ubuntu, but while booting bios dont give me options to choose for OS? Where did i went wrong? You helped me this much, i guess this will be the last step.

Comment: Ubuntu 15.04 UEFI boot with Windows 8.1, successfully installed dual boot. Thanks for boot-repair (Live CD).

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0):

first format a drive upto 30GB or more and then try to dual boot by the above steps.Make sure the space where u want to install ubuntu remains unallocated.

Comment: yup. i tried with 120GB. and it was unallocated, displaying free space in installation step. what is this UEFI warning?

Comment: ignore the UEFI warning